# How do I specify a window resolution for my bat file?

Tags: 20.04, wine, games, display-resolution

I have a Windows game (Europa Universalis 2) which I run through a mod (MyMap) executed through a `.bat` file in Wine (under Ubuntu 20.04). How do I specify a resolution for it when I try to to run it? It defaults to my Ubuntu resolution (1920x1080) when what I want is to run it in 1024x768.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the `.bat` file is run under Wine to start the game?

Comment: @Nmath I am voting to close the other two questions.